# Density clouds in 3d scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, data-visualization, plotly

ggplot2 has an awesome function `smoothScatter` to visualize 2d scatterplots with density clouds. The density clouds are really informative when the data is clumped together.

(Example image from my data):
[image]

Are there any ways to create similar density clouds for a 3d scatterplot?

I used `plot3d` to create a 3d plot of my data, but I'd like to visualize the density. Ideally, I'd like to keep the color scaled to the z-axis.  Failing that, is there a way to map color to the density?

I've noticed `plotly` seems to integrate with ggplot2. Is there a way to do this in that package?

(Example image from my data):
[image]

Comment: `smoothScatter` is a base function, and not from `ggplot2`.